# Docker: What is the best option to run angular?

Tags: angular, docker

I'm just beginner to Docker,

When i searched online for run angular apps in docker most of the articles shows that uses, nodejs image and just runing `ng serve`.
but when we deploy angular apps we run `ng build` command and host `dist` directory content. But whats the pros and cons of both of these options, and which one is the most suitable one ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: They have two different purposes. ng serve is for local development, ng build creates static assets for production environments.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yeah i know that, but my concern is about docker, running angular on docker is only suitable for development purpose or ?

Comment: You can use Docker containers for development or production too, e.g. an Nginx container can serve those static assets, which you can use a multi-stage build to create in a Node container: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: @jonrsharpe, got it thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my experience the best way to run angular in docker is by running the angular build in a intermediate "Builder" container and extract the compiled dist from it to another nginx or apache container to serve it.

```
FROM node:12.2.0 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.9 && ng build;  
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

By doing this you only store the dist file in the nginx container.